# How add quotes in a JSON string, using Java, when the value is a date

Tags: java, json, string, date, gson

I'm facing difficulties in a scenario that I need to read a JSON object, in Java, that has no double quotes in the keys and no values, like the example below:

```
"{id: 267107086801, productCode: 02-671070868, lastUpdate: 2018-07-15, lastUpdateTimestamp: 2018-07-15 01:49:58, user: {pf: {document: 123456789, name: Luis Fernando}, address: {street: Rua Pref. Josu00e9 Alves Lima,number:37}, payment: [{sequential: 1, id: CREDIT_CARD, value: 188, installments: 9}]}"
```

I was able to add the double quotes in the fields using the code below, with `replaceAll` and the [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5) library:

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson (obj);

String jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll ("([\\ w] +) [] *:", "\" $ 1 \ ":"); // to quote before: value
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll (": [] * ([\\ w @ \\.] +)", ": \" $ 1 \ ""); // to quote after: value, add special character as needed to the exclusion list in regex
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll (": [] * \" ([\\ d] +) \ "", ": $ 1"); // to un-quote decimal value
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll ("\" true \ "", "true"); // to un-quote boolean
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll ("\" false \ "", "false"); // to un-quote boolean
```

However, fields with dates are being broken down erroneously, for example:

```
"{"id" : 267107086801,"productCode" : 02-671070868,"lastUpdate" : 2018-07-15,"lastUpdateTimestamp" : 2018-07-15 "01" : 49 : 58,"user" :{"pf":{"document" : 123456789, "name" : "Luis" Fernando},"address" :{"street" : "Rua"Pref.Josu00e9AlvesLima,"number" : 37},"payment" : [{"sequential" : 1,"id" : "CREDIT_CARD","value" : 188,"installments" : 9}]}"
```

Also, strings with spaces are wrong as well. How could I correct this logic? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the string that you try to parse as JSON is no valid JSON. Where does it come from? You should fix the place where this string is produced so that it produces correct JSON.

Comment: It is a invalidate JSON, you need to fix this.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch thanks! Actually, my application doesn't produce this json. We receive a csv file with this information in a field, and, unfortunately, it is not possible correct it. I need to convert this string in a valid JSON.

Comment: The "fake json" is broken in multiple ways, did you notice the `Rua Pref. Josu00e9 Alves Lima` ? You'll need to find `u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}` sequences as well and convert these to the character with its unicode value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String incorrectJson = "{id: 267107086801, productCode: 02-671070868,"
            + " lastUpdate: 2018-07-15, lastUpdateTimestamp: 2018-07-15 01:49:58,"
            + " user: {pf: {document: 123456789, name: Luis Fernando},"
            + " address: {street: Rua Pref. Josu00e9 Alves Lima,number:37},"
            + " payment: [{sequential: 1, id: CREDIT_CARD, value: 188, installments: 9}]}";

    String correctJson = incorrectJson.replaceAll("(?<=: ?)(?![ \\{\\[])(.+?)(?=,|})", "\"$1\"");
    System.out.println(correctJson);
```

Output:

> {id: "267107086801", productCode: "02-671070868", lastUpdate:
>   "2018-07-15", lastUpdateTimestamp: "2018-07-15 01:49:58", user: {pf:
>   {document: "123456789", name: "Luis Fernando"}, address: {street: "Rua
>   Pref. Josu00e9 Alves Lima",number:"37"}, payment: [{sequential: "1",
>   id: "CREDIT_CARD", value: "188", installments: "9"}]}

One downside of non-trivial regular expressions is they can be hard to read. The one I use here matches each literal value (but not values that are objects or arrays). I am using colons, commas and curly braces to guide the matching so I don’t need to care what is inside each string value, it may be any characters (except comma or right curly brace). The parts mean:

- `(?<=: ?)`: there’s a colon an optionally a blank before the value (lookbehind)
- `(?![ \\{\\[])` the value does *not* start with a blank, curly brace or square bracket (negative lookahead; blank because we don’t want a blank between the colon and the value to be taken as part of the value)
- `(.+?)`: the value consists of at least one character, as few as possible (reluctant quantifier; or regex would try to take the rest of the string)
- `(?=,|})`: after the value comes either a comma or a right curly brace (positive lookahead).

Without being well versed in JSON I don’t think you need to quote the name. You may, though:

```
    String correctJson = incorrectJson.replaceAll(
            "(?<=\\{|, ?)([a-zA-Z]+?): ?(?![ \\{\\[])(.+?)(?=,|})", "\"$1\": \"$2\"");
```

> {"id": "267107086801", "productCode": "02-671070868", "lastUpdate":
>   "2018-07-15", "lastUpdateTimestamp": "2018-07-15 01:49:58", user: {pf:
>   {"document": "123456789", "name": "Luis Fernando"}, address:
>   {"street": "Rua Pref. Josu00e9 Alves Lima","number": "37"}, payment:
>   [{"sequential": "1", "id": "CREDIT_CARD", "value": "188",
>   "installments": "9"}]}

Comment: I made some tests adapting my solution to this approach that you proposed and worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

The following code takes care single quote present in JSON string as well as a key containing number

jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(" :",":"); // to trip space after key
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(": ,",":,");
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("(?<=: ?)(?![ \{\[])(.+?)(?=,|})", ""$1"");
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("(?<=\{|, ?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)(?=:)",""$1"");
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(""true"", "true"); // to un-quote boolean
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(""false"", "false"); // to un-quote boolean
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(""null"", "null");// to un-quote null
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(":",", ":"" ,"); // to remove unnecessary double quotes
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("true"", "true"); // to un-quote boolean
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("'",", "',"); // to handle single quote within json string
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("'},", "'}","); // to put double quote after string ending with single quote